# How to use lambda to deploy latest code put in s3 to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am trying to deploy my lambda function anytime I s3 bucket containing it updates.

If I know I have the the latest zip lambda code in a bucket I can simply use cloud formation to automate the creation and deployment of lambda function

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS CloudFormation CloudWatch Log Janitor Demo Stack",
"Resources": {
    "TestLamdaRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": [
                            "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Action": [
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                    ]
                }]
            },
            "Path": "/"
        }
    },
    "EbsBackupExecutionPolicy": {
        "DependsOn": [
            "TestLamdaRole"
        ],
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "hamedlamdapolicytest",
            "Roles": [{
                "Ref": "TestLamdaRole"
            }],
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "logs:*"
                        ],
                        "Resource": [
                            "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1111111111111:function:*"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "ec2:Describe*"
                        ],
                        "Resource": [
                            "*"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "LambdaFuction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Code": {
                "S3Bucket": "lambda-dep-test",
                "S3Key": "index.zip"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "TestLamdaRole",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            },
            "Timeout": 60,
            "Handler": "lambda_function.handler",
            "Runtime": "nodejs6.10",
            "MemorySize": 128,
            "FunctionName": "stg1-test"
        }
    }
}
```

}

But the problem is that as soon as I run the above lambda code then whenever user put sth in the bucket the latest code does not get deployed automatically. I Know it has sth to do with lambda but I am lost and I do not know which approach to use and where to start. Can you please shed light on this?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to achieve this. Create an event in S3. Whenever a new file is added, the event will trigger a different Lambda function which will update the original function (in this case: stg1-test)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tackled this issue:

- Enable versioning in the `lambda-dep-test` bucket
- In your `AWS::Lambda::Function` declaration in your *CloudFormation* template, use the `S3ObjectVersion` property in the `Code` section to specify which version should be deployed.

Now you can either update the template and specify a new `S3ObjectVersion` every time the lambda code is updated in the bucket or you can declare it as a parameter in your template and reference it in `S3ObjectVersion`. Both solutions can then be scripted with the packaging and uploading of your .zip file.

Comment: Hi, that would be great if you can give an example for declaring S3ObjectVersion as parameter to temlate in codepipeline, I have seen the aws doc regarding "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" but couldn't find out how I can use it for this case. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use frameworks like **serverless**. They make deployment easier using simple commands and easy to integrate with your CI. https://serverless.com

Comment: Thanks good to know about that framework. but what I want is automatic deployment without any user intraction. Does the framework do that ?

Comment: Serverless deploys the zip file to configured s3 bucket and triggers the lambda deployment. In your case you would still require user interaction to upload zip file to s3.